# Where can i find the CDN source for browser version of sanitize-html

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn

I am planning to use the sanitize-html at client side. And i searched but didn't find any CDN which is hosting it. 
Where can i find it/ is there any way i can add to some of the popular CDNs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the sanitize-html to cdnjs.com (one of the popular CDN for hosting javascript libraries) you can do it by raising a pull request to the following GitHub repository 
https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs

Answer (score 0):

JSDELIVR apparently has it, I hope this fits your requirements. Here: [sanitize-html](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sanitize-html).